# xcode geolocation: Getting coordinates before view is loaded

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, geolocation

I am trying to get the current location for the phone, and then send the coordinates to my webserver to process the data to return some results into my app.

The problem I am facing now is that the view loads first, then only it obtains the coordinates.

How do I get the coordinates first, so that I can send them to my webserver to process and send back the data so that I can be displayed on my view?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the controller that owns the view trying to send coordinates to your server before you get the coordinates? Is that the problem. You should show the code for that class.

Comment: I am following the tutorial from (http://www.altinkonline.nl/tutorials/xcode/corelocation/find-longitude-and-latitude-by-corelocation-xcode/)

It have a viewdidload as:

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
 
    [self setLocationManager:[[CLLocationManager alloc] init]];
    [locationManager setDelegate:self];
    [locationManager setDistanceFilter:kCLDistanceFilterNone]; 
    [locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters];
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

Comment: That doesn't really help. I don't understand your problem -- you say the view loads first and only then obtains the coordinates. What's wrong with that?

Comment: I need to get the coordinates first, then send it to my webserver. The webserver will process the coordinates and return some data in json format. That's why I need the coordinates to be sent first before loading the view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your view controller really needs the location information before it is presented, it can have the presenting view controller perform the location services before the transition. If there is no presenting view controller (i.e. the view controller that needs the location is currently the root view controller), you can introduce a new root view controller which will perform the location services before transitioning to the main view controller.

This presenting view controller should (per the Location Awareness Programming Guide) should create the `CLLocationManager`, initiate location services, and upon receiving the appropriate `didUpdateLocations` of the `CLLocationManagerDelegate`, it can then stop location services and transition to the main view controller. Perhaps this intermediate view controller should also show some nice "please wait" screen or a copy of the `default.png` image with a `UIActivityIndicatorView` while the location services are being performed.

In practice, though, you don't necessarily need to introduce this intermediate view controller. You could do it all with your primary view controller. You can employ asynchronous event-driven coding patterns. So, rather than requiring the location before the view is presented, you can defer the performance of the web services until after the location services have been satisfied. For example, [this simple test project](https://github.com/robertmryan/ios-wunderground-demo) invokes location services, and upon completion, submits a web request to a weather service, and parses the JSON response. No intermediate view controller was needed.

Note, though, that Apple frowns upon (i.e. may well reject) apps that only work if the location services succeed, so you may want to think about what your app is supposed to do if it simply is unable to use location services. You must gracefully handle that scenario, perhaps use the last known location.

Comment: Hi Rob, Thanks for attending this question. Well I am very new to xcode. You have any example on what you dais above?

Comment: Thanks for the update, well I'm getting lost on the 2nd part of moving from primary to intermediate & then back again. What I am trying now is that to load a view first to get those data into a singleton, then auto load the actual view to read the data from the singleton. But my new headache is when I try to load another view, it gives me the error: Storyboard (<UIStoryboard: 0xa0756c0>) doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'secondViewController'

Comment: I think my problem is that I actually created a storyboard for every class. I have class1.h, class1.m & class1.storyboard and such 3 files for every view. So am I doing something wring here??? Coz even after filling in the 'storyboard ID' is still get the error doesn't contain a view controller with identifier

Comment: Feel free to join me in [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19796/xcode-geolocation-getting-coordinates-before-view-is-loaded).

Answer (score 0):

Then why cant you find current location in before view so that while pushing to that map location we can pass these coordinates and call web service so that we can display data i think then we will get what you want